# Add margin to new lines in parbox

Tags: tables, parbox

My table

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\ra{1.3}
\caption{Well-known scheduling performance measures.}\label{tab:objectives}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Objective function} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Formulation} & \textbf{Interpretation} \\
    \midrule
    Makespan & $C_{\max}$ & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i\}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{The maximal completion time between all operations of all jobs} \\  
    Maximum workload    & $W_{M}$       & $\max\limits_{\forall k \in 1,\dots,m}\{\sum_{i=1}^{|B_k|} p_{ik}\}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{The machine with most working time; appropriate to balance the workload among machines} \\
    Total workload      & $W_{T}$       & $\sum_{i=1}^{o} p_{i\kappa(i)}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{Sum of the working time on all machines; appropriate to reduce the total amount of processing time taken to produce all operations} \\ 
    Total tardiness     & $T$           & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward} \\ 
    Mean tardiness     & $\bar T$       & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward} \\ 
    Maximum lateness    & $L_{\max}$    & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i - d_i\}$ & \parbox[t]{9cm}{Maximal difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when there is a positive reward for completing a job early} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table*}
```

looks like this

[image]

My question is how could I add a margin for every new like inside the `\parbox[t]{9cm}{}`. Like this

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable. What is `\ra`?

Comment: Please do not use `resizebox` on a table in order to make it fit into the textwidth. This will leas to inconsistend font sizes throughout your document. Instead, you could make use of `tabularx`. With `tabularx` and an `X` type column for the last column, you can also get rid of all the `parbox` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions of your table using `tabularx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\everypar{\hangindent=6pt}\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Well-known scheduling performance measures.}\label{tab:objectives}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lllY@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Objective function} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Formulation} & \textbf{Interpretation} \\
    \midrule
    Makespan & $C_{\max}$ & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i\}$ & The maximal completion time between all operations of all jobs \\  
    Maximum workload    & $W_{M}$       & $\max\limits_{\forall k \in 1,\dots,m}\{\sum_{i=1}^{|B_k|} p_{ik}\}$ & The machine with most working time; appropriate to balance the workload among machines \\
    Total workload      & $W_{T}$       & $\sum_{i=1}^{o} p_{i\kappa(i)}$ & Sum of the working time on all machines; appropriate to reduce the total amount of processing time taken to produce all operations \\ 
    Total tardiness     & $T$           & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward \\ 
    Mean tardiness     & $\bar T$       & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward \\ 
    Maximum lateness    & $L_{\max}$    & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i - d_i\}$ & Maximal difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when there is a positive reward for completing a job early \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*} 

\begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Well-known scheduling performance measures.}\label{tab:objectives}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}llY@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Objective function} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Formulation} & \textbf{Interpretation} \\
    \midrule
    Makespan & $C_{\max}$ & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i\}$ & The maximal completion time between all operations of all jobs \\ \addlinespace
    Maximum workload    & $W_{M}$       & $\max\limits_{\forall k \in 1,\dots,m}\{\sum_{i=1}^{|B_k|} p_{ik}\}$ & The machine with most working time; appropriate to balance the workload among machines \\ \addlinespace
    Total \newline workload      & $W_{T}$       & $\sum_{i=1}^{o} p_{i\kappa(i)}$ & Sum of the working time on all machines; appropriate to reduce the total amount of processing time taken to produce all operations \\  \addlinespace
    Total \newline tardiness     & $T$           & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward \\  \addlinespace
    Mean tardiness     & $\bar T$       & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{0, C_i - d_i \}$ & Positive difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when early jobs bring no reward \\  \addlinespace
    Maximum lateness    & $L_{\max}$    & $\max\limits_{\forall i \in 1,\dots,n}\{C_i - d_i\}$ & Maximal difference between the completion time and the due date of all jobs; appropriate when there is a positive reward for completing a job early \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table*} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In case there exists a cell in a row with more than one line, how can I center vertically the other cells?

Comment: @WillEnsaba: Probably `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` gives you the desired output?